# optimization of the log-likelihood, passing in different data sets

Tags: r, function, optimization, normal-distribution

I am trying to perform an optimization of a the log-likelihood of the normal distribution. The function for the log-likelihood works, and it recognizes the data set that is passed in but the optimization does not recognize that the data set is there?
If the we set `data_x=rnorm(100,0,1)` this code returns the correct answer, but i need to be able to pass in different data sets.

```
x <- rnorm ( 100, 0, 1)
loglike <- function( pars, data_x=x) {
  mu <- pars[1]
  sigma2 <- pars[2]^2
  numobs <- length( data_x )
  sumsq <- sum( ( data_x-mu )^2 )
  val.log.like <- -numobs / 2 * log( sigma2 ) - ( 1 / (2*sigma2) ) * sumsq
  return( val.log.like )
}

optimization <- optim( c( 0, 1), loglike)
answer <- matrix( optimization$par, 2, 1) 
answer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`optim` allows you pass additional parameters to the function you're optimizing.  In this case it would just be a matter of adding `data_x=your_new_data_set` to the optim parameters.

```
optim(c(0,1), loglike, data_x = your_new_data_set)
```

This is what the `...` parameter for `optim` is allowing you to do.  Check `?optim` for more details.

Comment: i tried this also but it still does not return the correct data...this gives the output:
                 [,1]
[1,] 4.996335e+54
[2,] 2.684172e+55

but the parameters should be close to 0 and 1. if you input     data_x=rnorm(100,0,1) for example as the argument to the function this works but i need to be able to change the data

Comment: I think your problem is a different one?  optim by default tries to find the minimum value for the function.  You can either write your loglikelihood function to return the negative log likelihood or you could add `control=list(fnscale=-1)` as a parameter inside of optim which will tell it to find a maximum value instead.  But the answer I gave is how you would pass a different data set in.

Comment: @user1840254, please don't forget to vote and accept an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `...` argument to optim:

```
y <- 1:100
optimization<-optim(c(0,1), loglike, data_x=y)
```